# How do I retrieve last word or character in PHP

Tags: php

Example string

```
$string = 'how-do-i-retrieve-last-word'
$string = 'how-do-i-retrieve-last-word-2'
$string = 'how-do-i retrieve-last word-123'
$string = 'how do i retrieve last word test'
```

I want to retrieve a last word on string above and the result should be :

```
word
2
123
test
```

Comment: @Jack Maney `substr($string,-1)` give me a last char

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php

Comment: @UnknownError - Well, do you want the last character of your strings?  If not, try something that will give you what you want.  This really isn't difficult.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regex with preg_match:

```
/\b(\w+)$/
```

**Code:**

```
if (preg_match('/\b(\w+)$/', $str, $m))
   var_dump($m[1]); // will print your last word
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$stringAfterHyphen = substr($string, -1, strpos($string, '-'));
```

Let me explain.  The `substr` function takes your string, starts at the last character and keeps going to the left until it reaches a hyphen.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match_all('/\w+/', $string, $res);
```

The `$res` array will contain all the words from the string, so you can easily select the last one.

Answer (score 1):

```
function lastWord($string) {
    $pos = max(strripos($string, ' '), strripos($string, '-')) + 1;
    return substr($string, -(strlen($string) - $pos));
}

var_dump(lastWord('how-do-i-retrieve-last-word'));
var_dump(lastWord('how-do-i-retrieve-last-word-2'));
var_dump(lastWord('how-do-i retrieve-last word-123'));
var_dump(lastWord('how do i retrieve last word test'));
```

Gives you:

```
string 'word' (length=4)
string '2' (length=1)
string '123' (length=3)
string 'test' (length=4)
```